# How to load background of parent content first?

Tags: html, css

I have design like this :

```
<div id='container'>
 <div class='box'>
  <div class='boxleft'>something left</div>
  <div class='boxright'>something right</div>
  <div class='clear'/>
 </div>
</div>
```

And I set CSS as :

```
*{margin:0; padding:0}
.clear{clear:both}
#container{width:100%; height:auto; background:#f1f2f3}
.box{width:95%; margin:0 auto; height:auto; background:white}
.boxleft{float:left;width:49%;margin-right:1%;}
.boxright{float:right;width:50%;}
```

Problem: Background is white of class `.box` be load later after class `.boxleft` finished the loading. I now want it load background follow the height of class `.boxleft`. So, How can I do this?

Thank for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a result of the float left and float right without having an height on both boxes inside the main box. Add this to your .boxleft and .boxright:

```
display:block
```

That should work.

Comment: Dear Brother, div itself is  a Block Element. They why we need to give display:block..No need at all

Comment: @DineshKanivu You are right, I was thinking about <a> elements, I used that before. 

After that comment I tried the html and css and it seems to work just fine for me. Got a link to show your problem?

Comment: Any way nobody see proper;y ur answer, so u din get minust Vote...You can changes your answer to more clear